# Ansible: How to specify an array or list element fact with yaml?

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-facts

When we check hostvars with:

```
  - name: Display all variables/facts known for a host
    debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```

We get:

```
ok: [default] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname]": {
        "admin_email": "admin@surfer190.com", 
        "admin_user": "root", 
        "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
            "192.168.35.19", 
            "10.0.2.15"
        ],...
```

How would I specify the first element of the `"ansible_all_ipv4_addresses"` list?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use dot notation

```
"{{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses.0 }}"
```

Comment: If you find yourself in a situation where this isn't working, check the array structure. VMWare disk info gets returned as an array, but the array index is a numeric string, so I had to do this to get it to work : "{{ disk_info.guest_disk_info['0'].backing_filename }}" in Ansible 2.9.5

Comment: Remember that if a dictionary key has a dash in it `-`, you must quote and enclose it in brackets. Eg. `stats.output.0['rpc-reply'].statistics`

Answer (score 8):

This should work just like it would in Python. Meaning you can access the keys with quotes and the index with an integer.

```
  - set_fact:
      ip_address_1: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'][0] }}"
      ip_address_2: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'][1] }}"

  - name: Display 1st ipaddress
    debug:
      var: ip_address_1
  - name: Display 2nd ipaddress
    debug:
      var: ip_address_2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same challenge when trying to parse the result of a command in **Ansible**.

So the result was:

```
{
  "changed": true,
  "instance_ids": [
    "i-0a243240353e84829"
  ],
  "instances": [
    {
      "id": "i-0a243240353e84829",
      "state": "running",
      "hypervisor": "xen",
      "tags": {
        "Backup": "FES",
        "Department": "Research"
      },
      "tenancy": "default"
    }
    ],
    "tagged_instances": [],
  "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

And I wanted to parse the value of `state` into the `result` register in the ansible playbook.

**Here's how I did it**:

Since the result is an hash of array of hashes, that is `state` is in the index (`0`) hash of the `instances` array, I modified my playbook to look this way:

```
---
- name: Manage AWS EC2 instance
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  # gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: AWS EC2 Instance Restart
    ec2:
      instance_ids: '{{ instance_id }}'
      region: '{{ aws_region }}'
      state: restarted
      wait: True
    register: result

  - name: Show result of task
    debug:
      var: result.instances.0.state
```

I saved the value of the command using `register` in a variable called `result` and then got the value of `state` in the variable using:

```
result.instances.0.state
```

This time when the command ran, I got the result as:

```
TASK [Show result of task] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.instances.0.state": "running"
}
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**